# How to pass argument from a class to another file

Tags: python, import, python-class

I m trying to pass from file_a the argument 'a' to file_b. So how can I get this variable in file_b

```
(page file_a.py)
class try():
    def pass_this():
        a = 7
(page file_b.py)
from file_a import try
```

And also if anyone can explain me if I can do it without using the class(if is it possible) it would help me

Comment: Python's basic organization is based on modules and packages, not on files.

Answer (score 1):

In `file_a.py`
You can just create a variable named a
`a = 7`

and in `file_b.py`, import this variable like:

`from file_a import a`

If ‘a’ is a class property or in some functions or methods use global key word

```
def myFunc():
       global a
        a = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set a as a global?

```
(page file_a.py)
a = 7

(page file_b.py)
from file_a import a
```